# How to setup a user personal photo folder to use with photo station in dsm?

Tags: user-accounts, nas, photos, synology

I've been messing around with synology's photo station and I've seen that a photo folder comes by default with users in the admin group.

Now I'm trying to create a photo folder for each user that is in the 'user' group and set permissions to the folder so that the user would be able to access it from the file explorer or the synology photo station interface.

How can I do that ? any good tutorials ? I've been looking at synology's website for help but did not manage to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did :

1) Create a folder with the user's name in the photo folder with an account that belong to the administrator group.

2) Go to the photo station web interface

3) On the left menu when you are logged with the administrator account go to :
settings -> User Accounts

4) Select the user you want to grant the permissions and click : Edit -> Assign Privileges

5) There you can grant any permissions you want

Answer (score -1):

It was terrible to get it working on "DS Photo" app. - mobile app (on iPad specifically) - I always ended with "no albums"... Even if I used correct login credentials...

The trick is nowhere documented - it was only luck to find out how to do it right - because I click on everything to know what it does... :-)

0./ Create new user which want use his own Personal Photo Station.

1./ You should follow guide to Enable Personal Photo Station Service for DSM Users from this article - it is quite simple (but somehow confusing) - https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/PhotoStation/account

2./ the tricky part is in DS Photo App login dialog - You should expand the username line so it shows as two lines login :-) - weird...

3./ enter in both username lines the same username and give password for them. and login... and it work (at least in My case :-) )

Images worth thousands of words... :-)

[1 - Standard login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ragXu.jpg)

[2 - Expanded username line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ximmc.jpg)

[3 - Blank usernames lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TYeT.jpg)

[4 - Weird but possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ0Ws.jpg)

[5 - Working solution... YES !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nteRi.jpg)